# Big o of merge sort

Tags: algorithm, big-o, mergesort

```
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r) 
{ 
   if (l < r) 
    { 
        // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for 
        // large l and h 
        int m = l+(r-l)/2; 

        // Sort first and second halves 
        mergeSort(arr, l, m); 
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r); 

        merge(arr, l, m, r); 
    } 
}
```

here's the code of merge sort

i can't understand how its big o is n log(n) while the the big o of merge function is n and the function merge called 7 times which is n - 1

if we have the following array as input {8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}

then the calls of merge would be

merge({8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}, 0,0,1)

merge({7,8,6,5,4,3,2,1}, 2,2,3)

merge({7,8,5,6,4,3,2,1}, 0,1,3)

merge({5,6,7,8,4,3,2,1}, 4,4,5)

merge({5,6,7,8,3,4,2,1}, 6,6,7)

merge({5,6,7,8,3,4,1,2}, 4,5,7)

merge({5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4}, 0,3,7)

then the result will be {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

so how big get calculated, i saw master method and i know its formula and saw 3 levels of the merge sort algorithm

but i want to calculate step by step

Comment: I don't have a formal proof, but intuitively `merge(arr, l, m, r)` takes `r - l + 1` steps. In your trace, if we're just looking at the values of `l` and `r`, we have `(0, 1)`, `(2, 3)`, `(4, 5)`, `(6, 7)`, which take `4 * 2 = 8` or `4 * (n/4) = n` steps in total. Then we have `(0, 3), (4, 7)`, which take `2 * 4 = 8` or `2 * (n/2) = n` steps in total. Then we have `(0, 7)`, which takes `1 * 8 = 8` or `1 * (n/1) = n` steps in total. All in all we have `log2(n) = 3` runs of the full 8 steps.

Comment: the "-1" is a constant, and we typically ignore constants when speaking of algorithmic complexity. After all, when n is very large, there's no practical difference between `n * log(n)` and `(n-1)*log(n)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time complexity for sorting an array of length n with Mergesort is `T(n)=2 * T(n/2) + O(n)` where T is the time complexity function and `2 * T(n/2)` are the recursive calls and `O(n)` is merging these two recursions. You can now prove that `T(n) ∈ O(n * log(n))` with a proof by induction over `m = log2(n)`if you want to. One such proof is stated here: https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/compsci220s1c/lectures/2016S1C/CS220-Lecture09.pdf

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to see it's O(nlogn) is by using recursion tree, since `T(n) = O(n) + 2T(n/2)`
you can draw recursion tree for T(n) like this:

```
             n
          /     \
     (n/2)       (n/2)
     /   \       /   \
 (n/4)  (n/4) (n/4) (n/4)
            .
            .
            .
```

In each row of the tree the sum is n (n = n, n/2 + n/2 = n, n/4+n/4+n/4+n/4=n,...)

And you have `log(n)` rows (because in each row n is divided by 2) so the total sum of the nodes in the tree is: `O(nlogn)`